# XMPP File transfer through XEP0065 SOCKS5 bytestream proxy in smack

Tags: java, proxy, xmpp, smack

I'm using the smack library to handle an XMPP/Jabber connection.  I know that smack has support for XEP-0065, but I don't see an option to specify a preferred bytestream proxy host.  For servers like Jabber.org, this is necessary, as the one provided in service discovery (proxy.eu.jabber.org) doesn't work.  Additionally, some servers don't list a proxy for service discovery.  How does one specify the preferred SOCKS5 bytestream proxy to smack?

(Clarification: This isn't about having smack connect to a proxy server to start its XMPP session; this is purely for use in scenarios where NATs prevent XMPP file transfers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some source diving and finally found where the code selects the proxy.  This isn't possible in [r13041](http://svn.igniterealtime.org/svn/repos/!svn/bc/13041/smack/trunk/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/bytestreams/socks5/Socks5BytestreamManager.java) of [Socks5BytestreamManager.java](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/~br%3Dtrunk/smack/trunk/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/bytestreams/socks5/Socks5BytestreamManager.java?u=3&r=13041#to423): in `establishSession(String targetJID, String sessionID)`, it enumerates the proxies from the XMPP server and immediately proceeds to gather the hostname and port of the proxies.  There is no provision to add a custom proxy host to the list.